# What ages are these nouns used to refer to?

Tags: word-usage

What ages (roughly) would refer to the people listed below?

- bimbo/a
- neonato/a
- bambino/a
- ragazzo/a
- giovane
- giovanotto/a
- figlio/a
- uomo/donna

and

- ragazzo/a

vs.

- fidanzato/a

Comment: I take the easy one: figlio/a is a lifelong condition (=son/daughter)

Comment: I'd split it into two (interesting) questions: one about the relative age ranges covered by *bambino*, *ragazzo* etc. (to which I'd add *ragazzino* which, though a diminutive form of *ragazzo*, has its own specific connotations; as well as the old-fashioned *fanciullo* and *giovinetto*); and the other about the different nuances (not just about age) conveyed by *ragazzo/a* with respect to *fidanzato/a*.

Comment: I agree with @DaG: could you please write two separate questions?

Comment: The TV announcer called “ragazzo” the winner of the last Paris-Roubaix cycling race: [Matthew Hayman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathew_Hayman) was ten days short of turning 38.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numeri indicativi, per dare un'idea.

- bimbo/a         [0 - 7 anni]
- neonato/a       [Primi mesi di vita]
- bambino/a       [1 - 10 anni]
- ragazzino/a     [10 - 15 anni]
- ragazzo/a       [15 - 29 anni]
- giovane         [15 - 29 anni]
- giovanotto/a    [18 - 25 anni]
- uomo/donna      [dopo i 30 anni]

Comment: Ho un figlio di due anni e ti assicuro che non è un neonato...

Comment: Questi numeri sono una tua valutazione a orecchio, vero? Interessante e in buona parte condivisibile (a parte che “ragazzo” a volte può arrivare a chiunque non sia decrepito). [segue]

Comment: Sarebbe interessante, ma impegnativo, fare una valutazione sulla base dei testi di periodici e libri. Una volta mi ero fatto dare da Google News una quarantina di notizie con la parola “ragazzino”: eliminate quelle in cui il termine era usato in senso lato (tipo “giudice ragazzino”) o in cui non era menzionata un'età, avevo trovato che la moda e la mediana erano 14 anni e la media circa 13,7, in un intervallo per lo più fra 10 e 16.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Tecnicamente un neonato è fino al primo mese di vita. Dopo diventa un lattante. E poi io alla veneranda età di quasi 40anni mi sento ancora giovane... ;)

Comment: Come diversi altri utenti possono confermare, *bimbo/a* a Pisa viene usato per persone fino a circa 40 anni...

Comment: Anche "ragazzo" può essere utilizzato COLOQUIALMENTE per persone di qualunque età a seconda degli usi, costumi e dell'intimità delle persone delle singole aree geografiche. In questo contesto però il fine non è trovare una convenzione assoluta, che non esiste. Ma fornire un'idea di una logica mediamente condivisa che sta dietro all'utilizzo dei termini su cui l'utente aveva dei dubbi.